# How Could My Chrome Profile Cause Chrome Extension Error: "Extension manifest must request permission to access this host."

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

When I install the "Page Redder" sample Chrome extension (https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples) on my main profile it works for most sites, but not for Google Docs.  If I try to use the extension to make Docs "redder" I get:

> Unchecked runtime.lastError while running tabs.executeScript: Cannot access contents of url "chrome-devtools://devtools/bundled/devtools_app.html?remoteBase=https://chrome-devtools-frontend.appspot.com/serve_file/@1c32c539ce0065a41cb79da7bfcd2c71af1afe62/&dockSide=undocked". Extension manifest must request permission to access this host.
>       at chrome-extension://cianfokdkklhngjaknijlbfkpbgbgaib/background.js:9:15

Where background.js lines 8-10 are:

```
chrome.tabs.executeScript({
    code: 'document.body.style.backgroundColor="red"'
});
```

However, if I do the exact same thing from a fresh profile it works just fine on Google Docs (it doesn't make the page red because of Doc's styles, but it doesn't cause an error).  I thought maybe one of my other extensions was interfering with it so I disabled all of them (including the Google Docs ones) and yet still have the same problem.

So, my question is, what could I possibly have in my Google Chrome Profile that would cause such an error in the Chrome sample extension, even with all extensions disabled, but only on Google Docs.  And if possible I'd like to know how I can "clean" my profile to eliminate it.

Comment: The cited URL is that of a devtools window. You probably have it open and focused.

Comment: I might have when I copied the error but I was having the problem on Google Docs site.  Thanks though.

Comment: The extension works on google docs document pages without any errors. It just doesn't do anything useful because the site's CSS overrides the style set by the extension. Anyway, it *must* work if you perform *exactly* the same sequence of steps without *any* differences, otherwise it's a bug which you can report on https://crbug.com

Comment: Try setting `chrome://flags/#user-activation-v2` to disabled - if it fixes the error, it's definitely a bug in the upcoming feature which needs to be reported (provided it's not already reported).

Comment: Show manifest json file in the question?

Answer (score 0):

This morning I restarted Chrome and it fixed the problem entirely :(  Sorry for such an unsatisfying answer.